# How to re-review changes to a pull request after a review on github?

Tags: github, pull-request

I am the reviewer for a pull request on github and would like advice on how to review revisions to pull requests. They submitted a pull request. I received it and made 20 comments, then the other party pushed commits addressing these comments. How do I **see changes in a view that also shows my comments**? I can see changes since my review, but that shows all changes and doesn't show my comments (I'd like to be reminded of what changes I requested).

This is similar to [How to review pull requests revisions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63180514/how-to-review-pull-requests-revisions) but they didn't receive any answers

Comment: I haven't found a better way than looking at the commit range for "changes since my last review" and the conversation tab in another browser tab. I like marking my comments as resolved when the PR addresses them, so they are collapsed in the conversation view.